Get WEBP via FFmpeg/thumbnails utility
I'm trying to create images that will be miniature frames for a video. When I run the command
ffmpeg -i /269.mp4 -c:v libwebp -vsync vfr -vf "select=isnan(prev_selected_t)+gte(t-prev_selected_t,5),scale=160:90,tile=5x5" -qscale:v 3 c_thumb%01d.webp

The response I receive:
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x558ddde533c0] No such filter: '5)'
[vost#0:0/libwebp @ 0x558ddde46880] Error initializing a simple filtergraph
Error opening output file c_thumb%01d.webp.
Error opening output files: Filter not found

I don't quite understand, on the previous version of the utility, this command worked.
True, the comma was escaped before the number 5. I tried this way and that, it doesn't work, how can I fix this?

In the ffmpeg documentation examples, the select expression is placed in single-quotes.
Try running it like that:
ffmpeg -i /269.mp4 -c:v libwebp -vsync vfr -vf "select='isnan(prev_selected_t)+gte(t-prev_selected_t,5)',scale=160:90,tile=5x5" -qscale:v 3 c_thumb%01d.webp


Thanks you.....
